# CMake question: Link object file in a different directory

Tags: cmake

Please excuse if this is a newbie question. Searched online and haven't found a better solution.

The test.cpp is performing test and utilizes the class defined in Input.cpp. Linker complains as below:  "*ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: Input::parse()*".

1. Adding this line in the test/CMakeLists.txt works, but the code looks ugly.

   *target_link_libraries(test ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/driver/CMakeFiles/Driver.dir/Input.cpp.o)*
2. Tried  target_link_libraries(test Driver) and got the error message:
   (target_link_libraries):  Target "Driver" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another  target.

   Here's a blurb from driver/CMakeLists.txt FYI

   *add_executable(Driver main.cpp Input.cpp)*
3. Not sure if I can export Input.cpp.o in driver/CMakeLists.txt, then replace the target_link_libraries line with something like

   *target_link_libraries(test Input)*

Here is Directory Tree:

```
/CMakeLists.txt

/driver: CMakeLists.txt, main.cpp, Input.cpp, Input.hpp
   
/test: CMakeLists.txt

/test/gtest: test.cpp

/build/driver/CMakeFiles/Driver.dir/Input.cpp.o
```

Any input is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Input.cpp` file to a library. Both `STATIC` and `OBJECT` libraries should do the trick. The following cmake logic uses an `OBJECT` library, since it's closer to the first alternative in the question.

**driver/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(driver_impl OBJECT Input.cpp Input.hpp)
add_executable(Driver main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:driver_impl>)
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(Driver test.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:driver_impl>)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works after adding some dependency

target_link_libraries(driver_imp OtherLib)